# Drupal views show all taxonomy of specified vocabulary

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary with the followings terms.

Benginner, Intermediate, Advanced.

I want to show a view that show these terms, but one term is associate to node, and I need stand out this term, but show all terms of this vocabulary, try to find the solution and nothing.

Comment: `one term is associate to node, and I need stand out this term` stand out as in ???

Comment: underline the term, show all terms of a vocabulary but only one is associate to node, but always show all terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you gotta do is create a view of Taxonomy Terms and use fields

[image]

Then use a template file for your view.

In your template file all you gotta do is load your node's taxonomy term field value and compare it the view's taxonomy term name. If it's equal we print the underline `<u>`.

```
<?php

    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $node_term = check_plain($node->field_name[0]['value']);

    if ($fields["name"]->content == $node_term) { 
        print '<u>' . $fields["name"]->raw == $node_term . '</u>'; 
      } else { 
        print $fields["name"]->content; 
      }

?>
```

Comment: thanks, i use instead a module tha show me all taxonomy, but this answer is great